# Do all pets deal damage?

Tags: terraria-mobile

In Terraria I have multiple pets. One of my pets is the baby slime. That is (so far) the only pet that will attack for me(on its own). The pet hornet will deal damage but only if I stand in a position that it is touching the enemy. Do all pets deal damage? What pets attack on their own? What pets must follow what the hornet does?

Comment: You mean pets or minions? one thing is to have a pet and another to have minions, minions are summoned with staffs usually.

Comment: Either. --------

Answer (score 2):

There's an important distinction to make here between *Pets* and *Minions*. Pets are intended to be cosmetic, something cool to follow you around that's just for looks, whereas Minions are specifically designed to assist in combat.

All of the PC *Pets* are pacifists, they don't do any damage at all. That said, two of the mobile edition pets do minor damage; the [Android](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Android) and [Elfa](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Elfa) pets. A number of the console ones do minor damage as well, namely the [Bat](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Bat_Pet), [Tiphia](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Tiphia), [Werewolf](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Werewolf_Pet) and [Zombie](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Zombie_Pet) pets all do damage.

With Minions, them doing damage is the rule, rather than the exception - I don't know of any Minion that *doesn't* do damage.

You can find the full list of pets [here](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Pets), note the last column which shows which ones can and can't deal damage. As Zerjack noted in the comments, the Baby Slime is actually a *Minion* rather than a Pet, summoned via the [Slime Staff](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Slime_Staff), which is why it does damage to enemies.

Comment: It's because the baby slime it's a minion too, an early game one though.

Comment: @Zerjack Ah, that would explain it. I saw a slime pet on the page and just assumed it was the same one without looking further into it. I'll update the answer accordingly.